# Recurrence Relation Equation for the Traversal of a Perfect Binary Tree of height $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Given the following problem:

> Assume that you want to traverse a perfect binary tree (each node has 0 or 2 children and all the leaves have the same height) of height $n$, under the conditions that the process of visiting each node takes a constant amount of time and is equal for each one, and that the time taken to change nodes is despicable. Given that the cost of an algorithm that resolves this problem is directly proportional to the number of nodes $a_n$ that has a perfect binary tree of height $n$:
>
> - Propose and resolve the recurrence that describes the succession $\{a_n\}$.
> - Propose and resolve the recurrence that describes the execution time of the algorithm if the time taken to process each node is doubled with each level and is 1 at level 0 (at the root of the tree).

I know that when traversing a binary tree, normally this is done recursively and while checking each node, we then start checking the the *left child* and *right child* of that node and so the process continues until the node is of a *null* value (non existing).

How do I mathematically reproduce this into a recurrence relation equation?

Comment: In English, "tree travel/trail" $\to$ "tree traversal"

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the correction, made the necessary changes.